# Alternatives to hiding content with css (specifically using display:none)

Tags: html, css

I have a multilingual welcome message, and introduction text that should only show up when the user hovers over their native language.

I've implemented the jQuery .hover() method fine albeit using jQuery but I now have the problem that when I reveal my "Welcome Message" my list items (languages) jumps down the page.

Basically on mouse hover I change the class from `hidden` to `visible`

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}

.visible {
    display:block;
}
```

Is there a better way of hiding the content, or better yet a way of anchoring the list items below the area where the header is set to appear?

Comment: position: absolute so they don't jump

Comment: Thanks. I'll try a combination of those two and see what works out best

Comment: positioning the 3 elements absoultely and altering the padding-top on each seems to have acheived this. visibility:hidden meant the langauge items were pushed to far down the page. I guess it would work if i dynamically changed the content of a single h2 to reflect the welcome message instead of stacking them all up

Comment: Luke, you can position 20 h2's on top of each other with absolute positioning. The padding hack is suspect. Make sure each h2 has exactly the same properties. Also note that visibility: hidden still allocates space for the element even though it is invisible while display: none completely removes it from the screen.

Comment: Also, `h2` already has `display:block` bt default, so you don't need to specify that explicitly. Just add and remove the `hidden` class as needed.